# Symfony entity datetime field update fails

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine

I am working on a Symfony project. In one of the entities I have to update a Datetime field, but each time I create a new Datetime object and set it to my entity property and call the flush() function I get an error saying:

```
An exception occurred while executing UPDATE tablename SET update = ? WHERE id = ? with params ["2015-04-23 15:31:50", 2]
```

FYI: Everything works fine if I don't update the Datetime field.

```
//Here is what I set to the Datetime field:
$eo->setUpdate();

//The function in the Entity
public function setUpdate() {
    $this->update = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    return $this;
}

//And the field declaration
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="update", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $update;
```

**EDIT**:

I forgot this:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "update = "2015-04-23 15:53:29" WHERE id = 2" at line 1
```

Any ideas on why I get that exception ?

Comment: did you have check the runable query ? what say the error ?

Comment: not sure that it is your problem, but for sure using reserved word `update` for column name is bad practice

Comment: I just edited the post to add the sql error.
@Nemutaisama Yeah i thought about that and have tried to change the property name. But no luck.

Comment: Could it be because of the table's "update" field name ?
Cuz i've changed the Entity's property name but not the actual field name in the table

Comment: Yes, this is reason - change table field name to `updated` like example

Comment: What a retard I am ... I spent like 2 hours on this ... thanks

Comment: @Nemutaisama I was going through my questions and this one hasn't an accepted answer. If you could just post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the error was due to the fact that I was using an reserved word `update` as a column name in my database -_-

Kudos to @Nemutaisama for helping me figure this out. As he didn't post an answer to this question I am doing it, hope it helps others.